# useEffect is not working in parent Component if child component is added in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass data to child component after getting data from API, if I remove the child component its working

```
const parentComponent= (props) => {
  const [loans, setLoans] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`api`).then((result) =>{ 
      let { data } = result;
      console.log('result', result)      
      setLoan(data);  
    });
  }, []);

 return(
  <ChildComponent data={loans} />
)
}
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: **Looks like a typo.** You have `data={loans}` but there is no `loans` identifier in scope. You called the state member `loan`. Your IDE and/or browser will have told you about this problem. Be sure to look at the web console whenever doing web development.

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the to the state `loans`. You have to use `setLoans` instead of `setLoan`.
Check this, it should work now.

```
const parentComponent= (props) => {
  const [loans, setLoans] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`api`).then((result) =>{ 
      let { data } = result;
      console.log('result', result)      
      setLoans(data);  
    });
  }, []);

 return(
  <ChildComponent data={loans} />
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`const [loans, setLoans] = useState({});`  use setLoan or changed name after console.log. You have done setLoans which is not equal to setLoan